# ¿como puedo solucionar este error del comando ping?

Tags: c++, c

hola tengo el siguiente programa ,por favor quisiera que me ayudaran a corregir el error,me aparece  ?
"ping" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {


    int dato; 
    cout << "ingrese datos:";
    cin >> dato;

    char url; 
    cout << "ingrese url:";
    cin >> url;
 
    stringstream comando;
    comando << "ping " << url;

    for (int i = 0; i < dato; ++i)
    {
        system(comando.str().c_str());
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ese no es un error con tu programa. Tienes disponible el comando en tu terminal?

Comment: no ,gracias ya lo pude solucionar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {


    int dato; 
    cout << "ingrese datos:";
    cin >> dato;

    string url; 
    cout << "ingrese url:";
    cin >> url;
 
    string comando;
    comando="ping "+url;
    for (int i = 0; i < dato; ++i)
    {
        system(comando.c_str());
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```